# Problem with boxplot: flat lines in function creation

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a problem with this function (i am new on R)

I want to create a simple function in which insert a gene(variable) to obtain a simple boxplot to compare two conditions (condition), but i obtain two flat lines and dont' know why.
In the function i want to have "condition" on x axis and the value of variable on y axis, and i remove initially na values from the df, but i don't think that was the problem.

```
    funzione <- function(variabile) {
    
    tab <- tab_n %>% filter(!is.na(Condition))
    tab %>% ggplot(aes(x = Condition, y = variabile, fill = Condition)) + 
    geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=0.75)) 
    ggpubr::stat_compare_means(aes(group = Condition), label.x.npc = "center", size = 3.2) +
    theme_bw()
}
```

Here are the first lines of the database I have.

| Gender | Condition | variable_to_insert |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | cond_1 | 5.6 |
| Female | cond_1 | 4.7 |
| Female | cond_2 | 4.8 |
| Female | cond_1 | 5.8 |
| Male | cond_2 | 5.1 |
| Female | cond_1 | 5.5 |
| Male | cond_2 | 7.9 |
| Male | cond_2 | 7.1 |
| Female | cond_1 | 2.9 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be great if you could share your example data by pasting the output of `dput` of your data (or `head` of the data). Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below is rewritten to accept a data.frame and a variable as arguments.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

funzione <- function(x, variabile) {
  x %>% 
    filter(!is.na(Condition)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Condition, y = {{variabile}}, fill = Condition)) + 
    geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=0.75))  +
    ggpubr::stat_compare_means(aes(group = Condition), label.x.npc = "center", size = 3.2) +
    theme_bw()
}

tab_n %>% funzione(variable_to_insert)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Data

```r
tab_n <- read.table(text = "
Gender  Condition   variable_to_insert
Male    cond_1  5.6
Female  cond_1  4.7
Female  cond_2  4.8
Female  cond_1  5.8
Male    cond_2  5.1
Female  cond_1  5.5
Male    cond_2  7.9
Male    cond_2  7.1
Female  cond_1  2.9
", header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: uaaa thank you!! yeah i had to embrace the variable... ok... unfortunately the "programming with dplyr" it's still quite difficult. Got it!